# Checking opencl version in C

Tags: c, opencl

I am working with OpenCL and i am trying to find out which version is of OpenCl is running on my system. I have done the library addition and other things to add openCL in my Visual studio 2015. All i want is a small code which tells me which version is running. Thanks

I found out a video where it is showed how we can check it in C++(CL/cl.hpp) but in my sdk it is not available but only C version (CL/cl.h) is available

Comment: Use [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

Comment: **ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
 ret = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_NAME_LEN, dev_name, NULL);
 printf("device name= %s\n", dev_name);**

Comment: This gives me my graphic card info not OpenCL version

Comment: yes but you should use `CL_DRIVER_VERSION` param value not `CL_DEVICE_NAME`

Comment: Thanks alot i got it but it did not came up with CL_DRIVER_VERSION but with CL_DEVICE_VERSION. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You should use `clGetDeviceInfo` along with parameter CL_DRIVER_VERSION according to this [doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html). Modify `cl_device_id` accordingly to your `clGetDeviceIDs` output.

```
 #include <CL/cl.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     char *driver_version;
     clGetDeviceInfo(0, CL_DRIVER_VERSION, sizeof(char*), &driver_version, NULL);
     printf("%s\n", driver_version);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help i got it

Comment: it prints non ascii char for me. My settings:  locale LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

[clinfo](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo) outputs OpenCL version, among many other things that might be useful.